# Elasticsearch pagination does not work (at least not in the way it would be naturally understood)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have around 38,000 documents in my index. I can only query 10,000 at a time according to Elasticsearhc.

**This query works:**

```
GET /vendor/vendors/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10000,
  "_source": ["_id", "name", "vendor_type"],
  "query": {
      "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "weight": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

this query does not! How am I supposed to get the next 10,000 documents If I can't even get the next 10 documents?

**ERROR GIVEN**

```
type": "query_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10010]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting."
```

**FOR THIS QUERY**

```
 GET /vendor/vendors/_search
    {
      "from": 10000,
      "size": 10,
      "_source": ["_id", "name", "vendor_type"],
      "query": {
          "match_all": {}
      },
      "sort": {
        "weight": {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This behaviour is explained in the documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html 

And the error message clearly directs you to use the scroll API, which is documented here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

The scroll API is the solution to your problem here.

Comment: Thanks. if you write this as an answer I'll be able to credit you for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the scroll API I was able to do what I needed to do.